# fgets() from stdin causing segmentation fault

Tags: c

I'm trying to use `fgets` to get a line from `stdin` but am repeatedly getting the diagnostic *"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"* which I believe is the error for when the destination doesn't exist - which is odd, considering I am allocating `Title`.

```
void getName(Song* songList, int globalCounter)
{
    char Title[100];
    printf("Title for deletion: ");
    fgets(Title,100,stdin);

    char *pos;
    if ((pos=strchr(Title, '\n')) != NULL)
        *pos = '\0';

    if (isalpha(Title[0]))
        Title[0] = toupper(Title[0]);

    printf(Title);
    remove_title(songList, globalCounter, Title);
}
```

Comment: In your last question you passed `globalCounter` to function too. Stop doing that!

Comment: @V.Kravchenko my friend also told me that was a bad idea, heh :-) I will make sure to remove it!

Comment: but the code works well here.

Comment: @AlterMann `fgets()` is accessing Title in `getName()` though, wouldn't this still be considered 'in scope'? Or should `Title` be defined outside of `getName`?

Comment: I dont see any probelm in it. please post the full code

Comment: You can try debugging. To see where the error occurs

Comment: I don't see any problem in the code posted here, but the `getName` function is pointless. The `getName` function reads the line from stdin, stores it in the local variable `Title`; as soon as you return from the `getName` function, the line stored in `Title` is gone.

Comment: @Ehsan The issue is definitely with regards to `fgets`, as when I use `scanf()` there is no issue, until it encounters whitespace (hence my attempted implementation of `fgets()`)

Comment: @unicornication try declaring Title `static` then test if the error remains

Comment: @MichaelWalz The function's purpose is simply to get user input, capitalize the first letter, and then pass input along to another function!

Comment: I dont think the problem is from `fgets` if it was `gets` maybe but `fgets` ain't buggy.

Comment: @unicornication Your new  edited code contains no problem.  Your problem is probably within the `remove_title` function. Run your program with a debugger which will show you exactly where the segfault occurs.

Comment: @MichaelWalz having removed the `remove_title` function, the segfault goes away, however the program simply ends as soon as the prompt shows.

Comment: @unicornication we can't help you because there is not enough information in your question. Once again use a debugger. You don't know how to use a debugger ? Well then it's time sto start learning it now.

Comment: @MichaelWalz thank you for the advice! will try that route :-)

Comment: printf( Title ); is exploitable.  Use `printf( "%s", Title );`

Comment: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" doesn't mean anything specific, just that you tried to access something you weren't supposed to access. The ultimate cause of it may have occurred much earlier. The most likely culprit is your list code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

1. You're allocating `Title` on the stack, meaning that it becomes invalid outside of `getName` function. Your code, as it is posted, doesn't have this issue, but I assume your actual code saves `Title` somewhere in the `songList` for later use. (ruled out when seeng updated code, though failure inside `remove_title` function is not impossible)
2. Since you don't check the return value from `fgets`, in case no string was entered you run `strchr` on uninitialized variable, possibly resulting in segfault. (still true for the updated code)
3. `printf(Title)` is a recipe for disaster. If `Title` happens to contain a `%` character, `printf` will try to access arguments that don't exist, and likely fail. Use `printf("%s", Title)` instead.

Comment: I updated my code to show it in its entirety, though, if I replace `fgets()` with `scanf()` it works fine, except only until it encounters whitespace. Is the assumption the same?

Comment: @unicornication Perhaps there's an error in your remove_title() function too. Did you try commenting out that call ? You should perhaps check if fgets() actually succeeds as well, and you should check that you actually read in at least 1 character after you've stripped off the \n.

Comment: @nos Actually `fgets` doesn't even guarantee to output a `\0` byte into `Title`, let alone `\n`.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev If fgets() succeeds, yes it does. It absolutely guarantees a nul terminated string. The code checks if the \n is present as well before stripping it off.

Comment: @nos The problem is, the code doesn't check whether `gets` succeeds or not.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Right - which was my suggestion as well.